# When I print a table using prettytable, I am not getting in single column

Tags: python, pretty-print

Can some body help me? I am unable to get the print in single column its printing in different column every time when I print

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import pandas as pd
for filename in os.listdir('Nse_Histrocial_Data'):
#print(filename)
symbol = filename.split(".")[0]
#print(symbol)
df = pandas.read_csv('Nse_Histrocial_Data/{}'.format(filename))
if df.empty:
    continue

df['20sma'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=20).mean()
df['stddev'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=20).std()
df['lower_band'] = df['20sma'] - (2 * df['stddev'])
df['upper_band'] = df['20sma'] + (2 * df['stddev'])

df['TR'] = abs(df['High'] - df['Low'])
df['ATR'] = df['TR'].rolling(window=20).mean()

df['lower_keltner'] = df['20sma'] - (df['ATR'] * 1.5)
df['upper_keltner'] = df['20sma'] + (df['ATR'] * 1.5)

def in_squeeze(df):
    return df['lower_band'] > df['lower_keltner'] and df['upper_band'] < df['upper_keltner']

df['squeeze_on'] = df.apply(in_squeeze, axis=1)

if df.iloc[-2]['squeeze_on'] and not df.iloc[-1]['squeeze_on']:
    data = ("{}".format(symbol))
    myTable = PrettyTable(['Stock'])
    myTable.add_row([data])
    print(myTable)
```

Image :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evnr4.png

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: There is a problem with your indentation. from what I gather, everything from `symbol = filename.split(".")[0]` to `print(myTable)` is in the `for` loop, is that correct? If that is the case you are initializing the table for each loop. try initializing the table outside the loop and printing it after the loop has ended

Comment: when i print outside the loop. i am getting only last line  as output instead of fill list --- thank you

Comment: As I've said, you need to initialize the table outside the loop as well